# Check your dependencies tree using

Tags: java, android, firebase

i have this error when exactly when adding firebase athentication in my gradle

[Error:Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[11.0.4,11.0.4], [15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 15.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
>   The library com.google.firebase:firebase-common is being requested by various other libraries at [[11.0.4,11.0.4]], but resolves to 16.0.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhFWW.png)

Comment: Can you post your gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

That error means that Gradle doesn't know what to do because you (or your dependencies) are declaring different versions of the same dependency and they are not compatible between each other.

As the error says:

> Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

You should rollback your changes and run:

> ./gradlew -q :app:dependencies

to check which dependencies you have that are declaring `com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement` and then you can try checking if you're using the latest releases of those dependencies.

Another option is to start playing with the [Gradle resolution strategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) using `force` and `exclude` for instance.

Anyway, the most important thing is to be sure what dependencies and which versions you're using. And the best way to do that is by executing the `:dependencies` task that you see in the error.

Hope it to be useful, regards!

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes i can understand the problem but i don't know how can i solve it.